# Python3 only opens in tcsh if I go to bash and then tcsh (anaconda)

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, csh, tcsh

I installed anaconda3 using the standard settings and mainly use tcsh.
If terminal opens in tcsh and then I type "conda" it works.
If I type "python" it shows

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

But, if I type "bash" and then "tcsh" and then "python" it shows this:

```
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 21 2017, 18:29:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

For reference, my .tcshrc file contains this:

```
set path  = ( $path anaconda3/bin . /opt/local/bin /opt/local/ncbi/blast )

alias python2 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7'

alias python3 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5'
```

.bashrc contains:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

.bash_profile contains:

```
source ~/.bashrc
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin
export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

I'm new to Unix and Python but need to set up anaconda in both bash and tcsh for a class. Any ideas?

**update:**

"which python" yields "/usr/bin/python" when I start up terminal in tcsh

If I switch to bash, "which python" yields "/anaconda3/bin/python"

"echo $PATH" in tcsh yields "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:anaconda3/bin:.:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/ncbi/blast"

"echo $PATH" in bash yields
"/anaconda/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:anaconda3/bin:.:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/ncbi/blast"

Comment: Please type `which python` for each case. This will show the path to the `python` binary the shell will be using.  It may also be illuminating to type `echo $PATH` for each case as well. It seems like in your bash startup scripts you are doing *a lot* of `PATH` modification.

Comment: In bash type: echo $PATH and which python to see your PATH and see what python-interpreter you're using.

Comment: @SethMMorton updated above

Comment: @AAA I bet that's not what your PATH looks like in tcsh *before* you switch to bash.

Comment: @SethMMorton yeah you were right. changed ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please take a look at this question and its answers to understand how the `PATH` environment variable works: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77898/how-does-the-path-enviroment-variable-work-in-linux.

Your issue is that in your `~/.tcshrc` you are not adding the Anaconda directory to the front your `PATH`, so `tcsh` finds the system installation first and uses that. To fix this you can modify the first line of that file to read:

```
setenv PATH ~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH:.:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/ncbi/blast
```

In `tcsh`, `setenv` serves a similar purpose to `export` in `bash`, so using just `set` would not reliably change your `PATH`.

As a side note, you appear to be making the same modification to your `bash` `PATH` over and over... you could clean that up a bit.

Comment: it gave me an error when I tried

    "setenv PATH ~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH:.:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/ncbi/blast"

but when I changed it to this, it worked:

    "setenv PATH ~/anaconda3/bin:.:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/ncbi/blast:$PATH"


I also cleaned up the files as you suggested, thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: Point of curiosity -- in bash, changing any variable already in the environment automatically updates the environment copy, so `export` isn't generally needed when modifying `PATH`. Do I understand you correctly that this isn't also the case for csh?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In `tcsh` it's not possible to modify a variable without using `setenv` or `set` (i.e. `PATH=blah` is not legal syntax).  `set` is only for local variables, so I would not expect this automatic updating to be possible.

Comment: *nod* -- the question I meant to ask was whether `set` would automatically promote to `setenv` if a variable already existed in the environment. That sounds like a rather speculative no.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm glad you picked up on the speculative part :)